# Element-wise function on BigQuery array

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I apply a function element-wise on a BigQuery array. For example, how can I add a constant number to each element in the `splits` column or convert the floats to strings.

```sql
WITH
  races_with_struct AS (
  SELECT
    "800M" AS race,
    [STRUCT("Rudisha" AS name,
      [23.4, 26.3, 26.4, 26.1] AS splits),
    STRUCT("Makhloufi" AS name,
      [24.5, 25.4, 26.6, 26.1] AS splits),
    STRUCT("Lewandowski" AS name,
      [25.0, 25.7, 26.3, 27.2] AS splits),
    STRUCT("Nathan" AS name,
      ARRAY<FLOAT64>[] AS splits),
    STRUCT("David" AS name,
      NULL AS splits)] AS participants),
  races AS (
  SELECT
    race,
    participant.name AS name,
    participant.splits AS splits
  FROM
    races_with_struct r
  CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(r.participants) AS participant)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  races
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it was easier than I thought it would be. One can just use `ARRAY` in conjunction with `UNNEST` in the `SELECT` statement. Basically it looks like this

```sql
ARRAY(SELECT transform(x)
        FROM UNNEST(array) AS x WITH OFFSET AS y ORDER BY y) AS transformed
```

So to complete the example from above

```sql
WITH
  races_with_struct AS (
  SELECT
    "800M" AS race,
    [STRUCT("Rudisha" AS name,
      [23.4, 26.3, 26.4, 26.1] AS splits),
    STRUCT("Makhloufi" AS name,
      [24.5, 25.4, 26.6, 26.1] AS splits),
    STRUCT("Lewandowski" AS name,
      [25.0, 25.7, 26.3, 27.2] AS splits),
    STRUCT("Nathan" AS name,
      ARRAY<FLOAT64>[] AS splits),
    STRUCT("David" AS name,
      NULL AS splits)] AS participants),
  races AS (
  SELECT
    race,
    participant.name AS name,
    participant.splits AS splits
  FROM
    races_with_struct r
  CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(r.participants) AS participant)
SELECT
  race,
  name,
  splits,
  ARRAY(SELECT x + 2
        FROM UNNEST(splits) AS x WITH OFFSET AS y ORDER BY y) AS transformed
FROM
  races
```

Comment: Brilliant, I found this particularly useful to map a function to each element of a json list after is has been extracted with JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY in BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT
  *, 
  ARRAY(SELECT '' || split FROM t.splits split) converted_splits,
  ARRAY(SELECT 5 + split FROM t.splits split) adjusted_splits
FROM
  races t
```

with output

[image]

Comment: This is an implicit UNNEST right? Is it keeping the ordering of the array?

Comment: @p13rr0m - correct :o)